# Apply existing categories from one Dask DataFrame to a Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, dask

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,102,101,99],'B':[1789,1890,1700,1980]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,102,104,105],'B':[1230,1890,1700,1980]})

da = dd.from_pandas(a, npartitions=2)
db = dd.from_pandas(b, npartitions=2)

da = da.categorize()
```

My question is how do I apply the categories of `da` to `db` such that the `db` DataFrame is categorical and has values `A:[100,102,nan,nan]` and `B:[nan,1890,1700,1980]`

Another question is How do I replace the categorical values with their codes after the above works

This is critical for data that is already split in to train and test. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cleanest to do using pandas 0.21.0 (recently released) and dask master from github. This allows dask to make use of the recently improved [CategoricalDtype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.api.types.CategoricalDtype.html#pandas.api.types.CategoricalDtype):

```
In [1]: %paste
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,102,101,99],'B':[1789,1890,1700,1980]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,102,104,105],'B':[1230,1890,1700,1980]})

da = dd.from_pandas(a, npartitions=2)
db = dd.from_pandas(b, npartitions=2)
## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: da2 = da.categorize(columns=['A', 'B'])

In [3]: db2 = db.astype({'A': da2.A.dtype, 'B': da2.B.dtype})

In [4]: db2
Out[4]:
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                             A                B
npartitions=2
0              category[known]  category[known]
2                          ...              ...
3                          ...              ...
Dask Name: astype, 4 tasks

In [5]: db2.compute()
Out[5]:
       A       B
0  100.0     NaN
1  102.0  1890.0
2    NaN  1700.0
3    NaN  1980.0
```